# Saudi Arabia Trasit visa for Indians

Tags: transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I am an Indian passport holder living in USA, I am travelling to India in December through Saudia airlines. I have a layover period of 10 hours and 13.5 hours respectively while going and coming back to USA in Jeddah in Saudi Arabia. I dont have any plans to go out of airport. Do I still need to apply for transit visa for either of my flights?

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, the software airlines use to determine the required travel documents, you may transfer in Jeddah without a visa if your transit time is 12 hours or less. They do have a sterile transit area, but looks like you'll need a transit visa for the return leg of your trip.

I don't know how they enforce the visa requirement within a sterile transit area, maybe someone here has personal experience and could answer that part more clearly.

Comment: 13.5 hours is > 12 hours, so transit without visa wouldn't be allowed.  Spending 13 hours in the airside transit area at Jeddah airport would also redefine hell - it's not something I'd recommend on anyone...

Comment: Yes I understand that the second leg is above threshold. And I absolutely agree, 13 hours in any airport would border on inhumane.

Comment: Check with the airline's office, most likely you will be ok.